# How to JOIN ON something in SQL that isn't an 'EQUAL' value?

Tags: join, locate

I need to form a join in SQL based on substrings in two columns, but the order of the substrings is not the same. In this example I'll use 'first name' and 'last name' as the required substrings. Is there something that will withstand this?

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| Parker, Mary | Mary Parker |
| Davis-Jones, Jim | JIM Jones |

I have been able to figure out less demanding cases using JOIN ON with LOCATE/TRIM/SUBSTRING but the code is not good enough for the above.

Comment: What brand of database are you using?

Comment: It's one at my job, I don't know what it is.

Comment: To find database type try these: `select @@version;`  or  `select version();` or  `select * from V$VERSION;`  (covers MSSQL, Postgres/MySQL, Oracle)  Knowing the dbms is important because they all offer different features (and syntax).

Comment: Hi, I believe it is Oracle, based on some updates they do which contain the name

Comment: Can anyone provide a solution for this?